# How to use summarise function in JuliaDB?

Tags: julia, juliadb

I am following the tutorial published at https://github.com/JuliaComputing/JuliaDB.jl/blob/master/docs/src/tutorial.md
a) While executing:

```
summarize(mean ∘ skipmissing, flights, :Dest, select = (:Cancelled, :Diverted))
```

getting:

```
Error: UndefVarError: mean not defined
```

b) Also tried:

```
summarize(mean, dropna(flights), select = :dep_delay)
```

getting:

```
Error: UndefVarError: dropna not defined
```

Please help me in resolving the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `mean` you must first import `Statistics` or `StatsBase`.
The other problem is due to the fact that `dropna` should be `dropmissing`. Also you have a wrong variable name in the second operation.

The lines that work are:

```
using Statistics
summarize(mean ∘ skipmissing, flights, :Dest, select = (:Cancelled, :Diverted))
summarize(mean, dropmissing(flights), select = :DepDelay)
```